# Swift Barcode Generation, making barcode only scan once

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, barcode, core-image

I currently am generating barcodes in my IOS app using CoreImage filter and I am wondering if its possible to make the barcodes only scan once, so after the first time it gets scanned it becomes invalid, similar to concert tickets and airplane tickets. Thanks!

This is the code I used to create the barcode image

```
  let barCodeString =  self.eventsName + " " + self.userName + " " + "\(self.ticketRow)"
  let data = barCodeString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
  let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPDF417BarcodeGenerator")
  filter!.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
  let barcodeImage: UIImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter!.outputImage!)
```

Comment: You would need to handle that on the back end or server. A barcode is just an image. It is up to the thing that scans the barcode to decide what it means and whether it is valid etc,

Answer (score 1):

To make a bar code that only scans once, you will have to use a server that keeps track of all of your bar codes. The basic flow could be like this:

1. Generate a bar code in your app with some UUID and register it with the server.
2. When you scan a barcode in your app, as the server if that UUID has been used
3. If it has been used, tell the scanner that it is invalid. Otherwise, tell the scanner that it is valid, and the server should mark the UUID as having been used.

This all relies on the scanning portion of the app- the bar code itself has no way of knowing if it has been scanned, unless the scanner alerts the server.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much